# What guarantees that a mined block will be accepted on the network? (Blockchain)

Tags: cryptocurrency

What ensures that a mined block will be accepted on the network? I mean, if I mine a valid block in the blockchain, and I transmit it to the network, what is the incentive to people accept it? Doesn't may happen a case where I mine a valid block and it get's refused?

And the reverse case, what ensures that if I mine a invalid block that this will be rejected by the network?

Just asking some newbie questions about it.

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography, This is directly related to mining. Did you look at Bitcoin.SE?